# Need a program to reverse the words in a string

Tags: string, cpu-word, reverse

I asked this question in a few interviews. I want to know from the Stackoverflow readers as to what should be the answer to this question.

Such a seemingly simple question, but has been interpreted quite a few different ways.

Comment: YOU asked the question, or someone asked you?

Answer (score 1):

if your definition of a "word" is a series of non-whitespace characters surrounded by a whitespace character, then in 5 second pseudocode you do:

```
var words = split(inputString, " ")
var reverse = new array
var count = words.count -1
var i = 0
while count != 0
   reverse[i] = words[count]
   count--
   i++
return reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take into consideration also spaces, you can do it like that:

```
   string word = "hello    my name   is";
   string result="";
   int k=word.size();
   for (int j=word.size()-1; j>=0; j--)
   {       
       while(word[j]!= ' ' && j>=0)
           j--;

       int end=k;
       k=j+1;
       int count=0;
       if (j>=0)  
       {        
           int temp=j;
           while (word[temp]==' '){
               count++;
               temp--;           
           }           
           j-=count;
       }        
       else j=j+1;       

       result+=word.substr(k,end-k);
       k-=count;
       while(count!=0)
       {
           result+=' ';
           count--;
       }
   }
```

It will print out for you `"is   name my    hello"`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from something called "Hacking a Google Interview" that was somewhere on my computer ... don't know from where I got it but I remember I saw this exact question inside ... here is the answer:

> Reverse the string by swapping the
>   first character with the last
>   character, the second with the
>   second-to-last character, and so on.
>   Then, go through the string looking
>   for spaces, so that you find where
>   each of the words is. Reverse each of
>   the words you encounter by again
>   swapping the first character with the
>   last character, the second character
>   with the second-to-last character, and
>   so on.

Answer (score 0):

This came up in [LessThanDot Programmer Puzzles](http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=102&t=2893)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void reverse_word(char *,int,int);
int main()
{
char s[80],temp;
int l,i,k;
int lower,upper;
printf("Enter the ssentence\n");
gets(s);
l=strlen(s);
printf("%d\n",l);
k=l;
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
{
if(k<=i)
{temp=s[i];
s[i]=s[l-1-i];
s[l-1-i]=temp;}
k--;
}
printf("%s\n",s);
lower=0;
upper=0;
for(i=0;;i++)
{
if(s[i]==' '||s[i]=='\0')
{upper=i-1;
reverse_word(s,lower,upper);
lower=i+1;
}
if(s[i]=='\0')
break;
}
printf("%s",s);
return 0;
}

void reverse_word(char *s,int lower,int upper)
{
char temp;
//int i;
while(upper>lower)
{
temp=s[lower];
s[lower]=s[upper];
s[upper]=temp;
upper=upper-1;
lower=lower+1;
}
}
```

Comment: Here is my programme.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (C++) will convert a string `this is a test` to `test a is this`:

```
string reverseWords(string str)
{
    string result = "";

    vector<string> strs;
    stringstream S(str);
    string s;
    while (S>>s)
        strs.push_back(s);

    reverse(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    if (strs.size() > 0)
        result = strs[0];
    for(int i=1; i<strs.size(); i++)
        result += " " + strs[i];

    return result;
}
```

***PS:*** it's actually a google code jam question, more info can be found [here](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1).