# c programming -reversing individual words in a string

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){

char *c;
char *y;
int len=strlen(c);
int i,k=0,j,m=0,t;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the string :");
gets(c);
printf("%s",c);
for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{
    if(c[i]==' '|| c[i]=='\0')
    {
        for(j=i-1;j>=m;j--)
        {
            y[k]=c[j];
            k++;
                        }

                       y[k]=' ';

        m=k;
        k++;

    }

}
y[len]='\0';
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
printf("%c",y[i]);

getch();
}
```

This program is to reverse the words in a string that is trying by me for a long time.i think logic i wrote is correct and i am getting different outputs each time..
some times output of previous execution will append in the next output.
can any one tell me where is the mistake

some times i am getting correct output with one letter missing.

one more thing i am adding when i am printing directly "y as an array it is coming, if i am trying to give as pointer it is not coming
i mean

printf("%s",y);   //output not coming properly

for(i=0;i

i want to know the exact difference

Comment: Not only is the code not formatted, it even contains commented-out lines which make it hard to read.

Comment: I'd like to know _why_ educational institutions are still using Turbo C (`conio`, `clrscr` and `getch` are a dead giveaway) when you can get gcc for free. Heck, you can even get MSVC for nothing as well.

Comment: sorry i ....will see to have proper formatted code from the next post

Comment: @paxdiablo:: it seems to be mainly the colleges on the Indian subcontinent - they still use Turbo C and some appallingly bad and out of date books by e.g. Kanetkar ("Let Us C", etc).

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [How to reverse individual words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777175/how-to-reverse-individual-words) and [Need a program to reverse the words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647247/need-a-program-to-reverse-the-words-in-a-string)

Comment: @satheesh, you have zero upvotes as well.  The only way you can thank people who share their knowledge with you here is to upvote their unswers and accept them when a particular answer has helped you.  Please consider the community when you ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
char *c;
char *y;
int len=strlen(c);
```

is an almost certain recipe for disaster: `c` is an uninitialised pointer and you are passing it to `strlen`. The *best* that you can hope for is an immediate core dump.

You need to fix that first, if only with the kludge:

```
c = malloc(1000);
```

Ther are better ways but probably the skill level where you're aiming with that code (not trying to be offensive there, just stating that this is CS101-level stuff where advanced user input functions are probably not needed).

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see right away is that you not initializing your variables and not allocating any memory for the string buffer.

```
char *c;
int len=strlen(c);
```

`c` in this case is not initialized and calculating the length of the string it points to would result in unpredictable behavior.

Then you do

```
gets(c);
```

`c` should point to some memory allocated with either `malloc` and friends or to an array (like `c[1024]`).

`y` is not initialized either.

Answer (score 1):

First allocate the required amount of memory to y. You are getting the result from previous execution because the previously allocated memory could be reused. So free up the memory when not needed and allocate when needed.